# How can I get the command key as an input in Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

I'm trying to create my own hotkey for my Shoes app but I'm not sure how to read the command key combined with another key, 
my code:

```
    keypress do |:command_1|
     alert "Pressed"
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the result.

```
keypress do |k|
  puts k.inspect
end
```

See what gets put when you select `command` plus another key and you'll know what to test for.